# ExpressJS client-sessions don't save session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I want to use [client-sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions) module with my Express backend. So I've installed the module and set it up to work with Express like this:

```
var sessions      = require('client-sessions');
app.use(sessions({
    cookieName: Constants.CLIENT_SESSION_NAME, // pi_client_session
    secret: Constants.CLIENT_SESSION_SECRET, // some long string here
    duration: Constants.CLIENT_SESSION_LIFETIME // 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
}));
```

But, for some reason, it's empty on every request. Here's the example:

```
router.get('/auth', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("CLIENT SESSION BEFORE: " + JSON.stringify(req[Constants.CLIENT_SESSION_NAME]));
    req[Constants.CLIENT_SESSION_NAME].test = "saved";
    console.log("CLIENT SESSION AFTER: " + JSON.stringify(req[Constants.CLIENT_SESSION_NAME]));
    return res.json({ sessionSaved: true});
}
```

And here is the output I get everytime:

```
CLIENT SESSION BEFORE: {}
CLIENT SESSION AFTER: {"test":"saved"}
```

I've tried from Google Chrome, Opera. The same result.

My setup is like this: ReactJS app proxies from localhost:3000 to localhost:3001 which is my express backend.
I've tried direct requests to express with Postman, and it saved the session normally. So the problem is definitely in Proxying from react to express and back.
My package.json file on react's side is as follows (I didn't include dependencies):

```
"scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build": "npm run build-css && react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001"
```

So the question is, how can I get client sessions using proxy like this?

Comment: Are you sure that the client-side request is passing the credentials properly? You should check if a) the client receives the session cookie and b) if the client sends that cookie on subsequent requests. Also, look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using fetch(), not XMLHttpRequest. But thanks for pointing me to keyword credentials :). I'll try to check it with fetch

Comment: The same applies, only a bit differently: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for pointing me to the right direction! I've added {credentials: 'include' } to my fetch() params and it all works now :) You may just type your reply as an answer here and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your React app is running on a different origin than your backend, you need to explicitly tell `fetch` to pass credentials (like cookies) with each request:

```
fetch('http://your-backend', {
  credentials: 'include'  
}).then(...)
```