# Using express sessions between expressjs server and a vuejs client

Tags: node.js, express, session, vue.js, vuejs2

Here's is the issue.
I'm using an `expressJS` server for a REST api server and a `VueJS` client with the help of `VueCLI` :

### Folder Structure :

```
.root
├── _server
|   ├── Server related files
├── _client
|   ├── Client related files
└──
```

[image: Folder structure]

I'm wondering if there's a solution to pass sessions from the server to the client like for logged in users...

Comment: you could use vue-axios to call that apis from client side

Comment: I'm already calling the api but how can I get the session and save it to use it on the client side

Comment: what do you mean by session ? and why do  you want to save it in client side?

Comment: For example when the user is loggen in, I want to check is there's a session for him to display the right content for him

Comment: if you want to save data about logged user you could make api call to get that data and save it in localstorage, but assigning privileges to an user in the client side could be a serious security issue

Comment: I'm not giving any privileges, and localStorage is not what I'm looking for, I'm just looking how to get express js session with vuejs client like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838860/expressjs-client-sessions-dont-save-session

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.
Authenticate the user with `JWT` and using `Vuex` to make the state of the logged in user